# Button only receive event when clicked a lot of times in my HTML5 app

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I´m creating a simple HTML5 app using Intel XDK. The application uses AJAX to find information about a postal code. The problem is that, the button only works when clicked more than five or six times. I never seen that before! I checked it with an Alert() function and I figured out that the event is not being executed before I click a number of times. I tried to find a solution searching google but no one seems to get this issue. I know it´s a bug, but I gave my best to find it without success. 
Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vdaxw83cgrf6h6/Teste.zip?dl=0) to my complete code. Thanks in advance!
As a some friends pointed out, I need to narrow down the problem. I think the code bellow is responsible for the issue:

```
(function()
{
 function register_event_handlers()
 {

    $(document).on("click", "#btnConsultar", function(evt)
    {
        alert("I do not appear before 5 clicks!");
        var cep = $("#textCEP").val();
        $.ajax( "//viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/piped/?callback=?").success(function(data) {            $("#textResultado").val(data);
    }).fail(function(data) {
        $("#textResultado").val(data);
    });
    return true;
});

 }
 document.addEventListener("app.Ready", register_event_handlers, false);
})();
```

Comment: Add the code to your question. Links can and do die and in the event that someone finds this question later on they need to be able to know exactly what question was answered. You are also much more likely to receive help if users don't have to go off to another website, download something, and then start reading through your code.

Comment: Yes friend, but I dont know what piece of code is the issue, the code is so big to put here, and it has some CSS, HTML and some other files that may or not be part of the problem... Thanks for the advice!

Comment: then you need to narrow it down to the element(s) and any relevant Javascript.